# How to increase max line length when printing Clojure data

Tags: clojure

I am writing content to an `edn` file and would like the maximum width of the lines to be greater than the current default value:

```
(use 'clojure.pprint)
nil
user=> *print-right-margin*
72
```

This seems to accord with the output I am currently getting. But how to increase the default value?

This is the function I'm using to write out the `edn` file:

```
(defn pp-str [x] (-> x clojure.pprint/pprint with-out-str))
```

Example use:

```
(spit "foo.edn" (u/pp-str foo))
```

Where `foo` might be some hiccup, or other Clojure data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try rebinding `*print-right-margin*` either outside the `pp-str` function:

```
(binding [*print-right-margin* 1000]
  (spit "foo.edn" (u/pp-str foo)))
```

or from inside:

```
(defn pp-str [x] 
  (binding [*print-right-margin* 1000]
    (-> x clojure.pprint/pprint with-out-str))))
```

this would temporarily redefine the value for the scope of the enclosed block. This should help

Answer (score 1):

Notice in the docs for `*print-right-margin` that it's a 'dynamic var'. This means that you can temporarily change it using `binding`, for the current thread.

`(binding [*print-right-margin* 42]
  (pprint my-great-data))`

Dynamic vars typically follow the `*var*` naming convention. Other examples are `*out*` and `*err*`.