# Calculate winrate with loop recur

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

```
(defn to-percentage [wins total]
  (if (= wins 0) 0
      (* (/ wins total) 100)))

(defn calc-winrate [matches]
  (let [data (r/atom [])]
    (loop [wins 0
           total 0]
      (if (= total (count matches))
        @data
        (recur (if (= (get (nth matches total) :result) 1)
                 (inc wins))
               (do
                 (swap! data conj (to-percentage wins total))
                 (inc total)))))))

(calc-winrate [{:result 0} {:result 1} {:result 0} {:result 1} {:result 1}])
```

I got the following code, `calc-winrate` on the last line returns `[0 0 50 0 25]`. I'm trying to make it return `[0 50 33.33333333333333 50 60]`.

Am I doing the increment for `wins` wrong? When I print the value of `wins` for each iteration I get

```
0
nil
1
nil
1
```

so I'm guessing I somehow reset or nil `wins` somehow?

Also, could this whole loop be replaced with map/map-indexed or something? It feels like map would be perfect to use but I need to keep the previous iteration wins/total in mind for each iteration.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a lazy solution using `reductions` to get a sequence of running win totals, and transducers to 1) join the round numbers with the running totals 2) divide the pairs 3) convert fractions to percentages:

```
(defn calc-win-rate [results]
  (->> results
       (map :result)
       (reductions +)
       (sequence
         (comp
           (map-indexed (fn [round win-total] [win-total (inc round)]))
           (map (partial apply /))
           (map #(* 100 %))
           (map float)))))

(calc-win-rate [{:result 0} {:result 1} {:result 0} {:result 1} {:result 1}])
=> (0.0 50.0 33.333332 50.0 60.0)
```

Comment: When I convert to a vector with `(into []` I get every entry on new line, any clue why?

Comment: @Olle do you mean the result prints across multiple lines in the REPL? That's controlled by a REPL setting, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39368753/how-to-increase-max-line-length-when-printing-clojure-data/39373753). This doesn't affect the _value_ of the result, only how it's printed.

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate the running win rates as follows:

```
(defn calc-winrate [matches]
  (map
    (comp float #(* 100 %) /)
    (reductions + (map :result matches))
    (rest (range))))
```

For example,

```
=> (calc-winrate [{:result 0} {:result 1} {:result 0} {:result 1} {:result 1}])
(0.0 50.0 33.333332 50.0 60.0)
```

---

The `map` operates on two sequences:

- `(reductions + (map :result matches))` - the running total of wins;
- `(rest (range))))` - `(1 2 3 ... )`, the corresponding number of matches.

The `map`ping function, `(comp float #(* 100 %) /)`,

- divides the corresponding elements of the sequences,
- multiplies it by 100, and
- turns it into floating point.

Comment: Very nice use of `map` with multiple collection inputs

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution with reduce:

```
(defn calc-winrate [matches]
  (let [total-matches (count matches)]
    (->> matches
         (map :result)
         (reduce (fn [{:keys [wins matches percentage] :as result} match]
                  (let [wins (+ wins match)
                        matches (inc matches)]
                    {:wins wins
                     :matches matches
                     :percentage (conj percentage (to-percentage wins matches))}))
                 {:wins 0 
                  :matches 0
                  :percentage []}))))
```

So the thing here is to maintain (and update) the state of the calculation thus far.
We do that in the map that's

```
 {:wins 0
  :matches 0
  :percentage []}
```

Wins will contain the wins so far, matches are the number of matches we've analysed, and percentage is the percentage for so far.

Answer (score 0):

```
 (if (= (get (nth matches total) :result) 1)
             (inc wins))
```

your if shall be written as follows:

```
 (if (= (get (nth matches total) :result) 1)
             (inc wins)
             wins  ; missing here , other wise it will return a nil, binding to wins in the loop
)
```

if you go with a reductions ,

```
(defn calc-winrate2 [ x y ]
  (let [ {total :total r :wins  } x
        {re :result } y]
    (if (pos? re )
      {:total (inc total) :wins (inc r)}
      {:total (inc total) :wins r}
      )
    )
  )

(reductions calc-winrate2 {:total 0 :wins 0} [   {:result 0} {:result 1} {:result 0} {:result 1} {:result 1}])
```